# Length of function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac{x}{2^n}$  and $x \in \mathbb{R}$
Prove that it is function class C1 and length $F|_{[0,3001]} $is less than $3001\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

First show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac{x}{2^n}$$ 
converges pointwise. Than show that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sin \frac{x}{2^n}\right)' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cos \frac{x}{2^n}$$
converges uniformly. Than [we know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) that 
$$F'(x) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cos \frac{x}{2^n}.$$
And since $\frac{1}{2^n} \cos \frac{x}{2^n}$ are continuous and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cos \frac{x}{2^n}$ converges uniformly, than $F'(x)$ is continuous.

And for the length use this inequality
$$
|F'(x)| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n} = 1.
$$